# Ruby require File (not file)

Tags: ruby, file, encryption

I have an encrypted file `file = File.new("encrypted.file", "r")` that I would like to require in Ruby after decryption. I do not want to decrypt, save, require, and delete the file.

What I do now is:

```
str=""
file.each do |line|
     str+=line
end#do

str = doSomeDecryption(str)
```

I would like to `require str` in some way. Any ideas? `eval(str)` is not an option; it really has to be 'requireable'.

Comment: What do you mean by "require?" Do you want to throw an exception if the string is empty? Or make some sort of validation fail?

Comment: After decryption it's a valid ruby script. So just as you can require myscript.rb, i would like to require, in some way: str But, eval is not an option...

Comment: I'm curious why you don't want the file to remain unencrypted on your host? Is it that insecure and you have no control over access to the directory?

Comment: If require really needs a file, i guess there is no other way than save the decypted string to a file, require the file and delete afterwards

Comment: I totally have no control to who can access the file. It's part of a software that will be installed on many pc's..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, require doesn't load a file, it loads a resource; with the right overload of Kernel#require, you can do almost anything. Some folks have made versions that use open-uri to load code from a remote server. If you want to implement this in pure Ruby, you will need to use `eval`. See http_require (https://github.com/astrails/http_require) for its implementation.

If you want to implement this as an extension, you may be able to reduce the potential attack surface area, but you're still going to be implementing either a save-to-disk-then-require or an `eval`. (Strictly speaking, although I can't find the code in the interpreter right at the moment, `require` itself essentially does an `eval`.)

Answer (score 0):

isn't there an evil eval :)
I do not recommend its use.

Comment: Eval is not an option. Isn't there any option to require a 'virtual' file?

Comment: a virtual file is also a file. you sad that you don't want files :)

Comment: Maybe 'virtual' file was the wrong name. I could write a file from str making it a valid .rb and then require it. But, isn't there a shortcut?

Answer (score 0):

There are various libraries which do this already:

- RubyGems patches `require` to automatically activate Gems
- OCRA, Crate and friends patch `require` to load from a `TEXT` column in an encrypted SQLite database etc.

You can look there for how they approach this problem.

Ruby 2.0 will have an API that allows you to register handlers to hook into the `require` process.